# Function returning value too fast

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm using CloudKit in a project and I'm loading data from the cloud to check if the user is already in the cloud or not, but when I call the `loadUser()` function, the code already returns a value BEFORE the actual value shows up! Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var shouldSaveUser = Bool()
    shouldSaveUser = loadUser()

    if shouldSaveUser == true {
        send2Cloud()
    } else {
        print("\nUSER ALREADY IN THE CLOUD\n")
    }
}

func loadUser() -> Bool {

    users = [CKRecord]()

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: predicate)

    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results: [CKRecord]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) {
            records, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        if let users = results {
            self.users = users
            print("\nHow many users: \(self.users.count)\n")

            if self.users.count != 0 {
                self.aux = false
            } else {
                self.aux = true
            }
            print("\n\(self.aux)")
        }
    }
    print("\n\(self.aux)")
    return self.aux
}
```

Right now, I have 0 users, so `self.aux` should be equal `true`, which happens only after the `loadUser()` returns a wrong value! Here it is the order that appears in the console:

```
false
USER ALREADY IN THE CLOUD
How many users: 0
true
```

It should be `true` but by the time that this changes to `true` is already too late!
Does anyone knows how to fix this? Any help is very appreciated!! Thanks, guys!

Comment: You can't use normal return values when working with asynchronous actions. Setup `loadUser` with a completion handler instead of a return value.

Comment: Why do you have two calls to `performQuery`, one inside the other?

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks a lot! Did not know about that. Your answer was really helpful!!

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, that's a mistake, I already got rid of that in my code!

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to run  `publicData.performQuery` in a background  thread and when its done it calls

```
  if error != nil {
     print(error?.localizedDescription)
                  }
```

So the code after the `publicData.performQuery` outside the block runs before the result is returned. So you should put the code that depends on this query inside `if error != nil { //CODE HERE }`